# Django-social-auth {% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %} is not adding a user to db

Tags: python, django, authentication, openid, google-signin

`<a class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-sm" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Verbinden</a>`
Why does this Link not add an user to the social_auth_usersocialauth table. Everything else in the login procedure works fine. What are the possibilities?
If you need more code just write an 
comment

Comment: What does `social:begin` refer to?

Comment: To the begin method in python-social-auth